# Connection string

Tags: string

I have a form (freeform) in my EE site working just fine.
My client ask me for a connection string because he wants to get the information fill up in the form directly in his own system database.

I've never hear about connection string before. Is it possible? What is neccessary to achieve it?

Francois

Answer (score 1):

A connection string would simply be the database connection details formatted in a way to allow some software to connect to the database.

A list of MySQL connection strings can be found at http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Essentially, given the database hostname, database username, database password, and the database name from your system/expressionengine/config/database.php file should be enough for someone to create their own.

Comment: Thanks foamcow, I thought it was something more complex.